# Building xamarin.forms Android solution results in BadImageFormatException of Monoandroid10

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Been developing an application which, as for now, runs only on iOS and everything runs great here. Now I want to run the Android Project, but I keep getting this error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA0009: Error while loading assembly: /Users/ulriksandberg/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.loader/4.3.0/lib/MonoAndroid10/*.* ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.

I'm running on the local emulator Android_Accelerated_Oreo, or atleast I want to.

Comment: Check that all the packages installed on the Forms Project are also installed on the Android Project. And also that they have the same version.

Comment: Tried to add all the nuget package from the forms project, but to no avail. It keep giving me the `System.BadImageFormatException: `

Answer (score 0):

> XA0009 Error while loading assemblies: {0}.

Much of the reason for this error is due to the fact that the program is loading NuGet packages or other bound library files.You can try the following method：

1. Check if there are any unused Nuget packages in the project, but keep a
   reference to them, then you need to remove all references related to
   them.
2. Check if there are incorrectly installed Nuget packages, please
   reinstall them
3. If there is a library file reference, the same processing as the
   Nuget package

Comment: Hello, i've tried all of the above the only nuget packages installed are the microsoft.appcenter nuget packages as well as Live.xaml. They have all been reinstalled and i have made sure that it is the same version in all of my packages. The problem still persists with the error msg: `System.BadImageFormatException`

Comment: @Ulrik.S Okey,form shared error code, do you have some code using about image .